# @Secured("root") dosen't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i try to use `@Secured` but it doesn't give permission for all role users.
my configuration is like that :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception{

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, true from users where username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username as principal, r.role as role from users u, role r where"
                    + " u.roule_id = r.role and username = ?");
//          .rolePrefix("role_");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/js/**","/app/**","/images/**","/partials/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .permitAll()
//                  .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/pages/303.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new CustomLoginSuccessHandler("/");
    }

}
```

and my service :

```
@RestController
public class ServerService {

        ...

        @Secured("root")
        @RequestMapping(value="getServers",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<ServerDTO> getServers(@RequestParam String st) {
           ...
        }
}
```

Comment: I think `@Secured` works with `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` you should try `@Secured("ROLE_ROOT")` instead

Comment: @Kakawait in my database i have role called "root"

Comment: @ElgallatiNoreddine I know but `@Secured` is waiting for *security config attributes*. Those attributes can be a *role* but other. In order to make distinction Spring prefix your role with `ROLE_`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `@Secured("ROLE_ROOT")`

Spring [`@Secured`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal) is waiting for *security attributes* that is a bit different than your *raw* roles.

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal)

> The prefix "`ROLE_`" is a marker which indicates that a simple comparison with the user’s authorities should be made. In other words, a normal role-based check should be used. Access-control in Spring Security is not limited to the use of simple roles (hence the use of the prefix to differentiate between different types of security attributes)

More details on http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-role-prefix

Comment: thank u, i resolved the problem by adding the prefix ROLE_